# How can I generate a planet from this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a game set on a randomly generated planet. I came up with a script that will generate the noise required but have no idea how to generate the tiles. I want to generate a world similar to Terraria but on a circular planet. I'd like to be able to control how deep each layer is.

```
public class CircularNoise
{
    System.Random random = new System.Random();
    float offsetX, offsetY;
    float scale;

    public CircularNoise(float scale)
    {
        offsetX = random.Next(100000);
        offsetY = random.Next(100000);
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public float getNoise(float radian)
    {
        float r = radian % (float)Math.PI*2;
        if(r < 0.0){r += (float)Math.PI*2;}
        return Mathf.PerlinNoise(offsetX + (float)Math.Cos(r) * scale, offsetY + (float)Math.Sin(r) * scale);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: *I have this water color box, how to create a Mona Lisa* ... thats about the scope of question you are posting. Not a good fit for SO. Please try to solve it using Google and other forums for unity / world generation and come back if you have a specific problem. A reread of  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) might also be a good Idea. If your world creating code is a bit more functional and you got a specific problem:  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This might give you a starting point: [GENERATING TERRAIN in Unity - Procedural Generation Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFvwyu_ZKfU)

Comment: this is my favorite tutorial: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise-derivatives/